# OS Maverick broke MySQL?

Tags: mysql, configuration, installation, osx-mavericks

Before upgrading to OS X 10.9.4 , when I do `mysql -u root -p mysql`, I only need to hit `enter` when prompted for password. After the upgrade, I get the following error message:

```
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

It seems some configuration files are missing, or mysql installation is broken in the process. `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` no longer points to mysql executable, instead I find this `mysql-5.5.25a-osx10.6-x86` and  `mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64`. I also cannot find `my.cnf` in either /home or /etc directory. Trying to install using `brew install mysql` gives this `Warning: mysql-5.6.19 already installed`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found an answer by now but just in case, the response to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/774964/mysql-server-wont-start-after-mavericks-upgrade) worked for me:  I created a symlink from mysql to, in my case, mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64in the /usr/local/ directory.

The other thing that sort of worked was [changing the mysql.server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027479/mac-os-x-mysql-preference-pane-doesnt-work) file to include the following:

```
basedir=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64
datadir=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64/data
```

I also had to download the mysql dmg package, install the startup item and modify the file /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM to point to the new mysql-5.5 directory.  I couldn't get the prefpane to work using this more complicated method.

So I switched back to the symlink, which seemed to fix everything.  Not sure if it's "correct", but it's been working so far.