# Using MS SQL Server on Snow Leopard Server with Coldfusion

Tags: sql-server-2008, osx-snow-leopard, coldfusion-8

I was wondering if it was possible or is there a way of using that all together on one machine without virtualization

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server require Windows no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The only option for running Windows apps directly would be something like Crossover but SQL Server is known not to work with Crossover (or WINE on Linux for that matter).

Unlike typical Windows apps, SQL Server is likely to be deeply integrated with the OS for operations like disk access, etc.

With enough memory, virtualisation is probably the best way to go - you should be able to access the 'remote' virtualised database easily enough.

Comment: good thanks....  
how about MAMP? 
as far as I can see (I haven't installed MAC OS 10 Server yet) Apache is already installed, does that mean I also get mySQL and PHP? or do I have install it myself.
If I have install it myself, than i will have to make it play nice with Apache... if I install MAMP everything works out of the box.
But if I use mamp I won't be able to use the "Cool" Mac OS 10 Server dashboard!! 
any comments here?

Comment: There's a previous question on this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293484/easiest-way-to-activate-php-and-mysql-on-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard

PHP is definitely installed (along with Ruby, Python, etc). I'm not sure if mySQL is installed by default in the client version (it is in the Server OS). I don't think it is.

If SQL Server isn't a necessity and you just need a database, you should consider sqllite (simple option if you just need an object store for an application), or postgres if you need something equivalent to Oracle / SQL Server.