# PHP : Mongo class not found

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to run MongoDB with PHP. I have XAMPP 1.7.7 installed on my machine (Windows XP - 32 bit).

The PHP version is 5.3.8 and Apache version is 2.2.21.
I installed the PHP MongoDB drivers as was given on their instructions page. I have the php_mongo.dll from this zip - mongo-1.1.4-php5.3vc9ts ( because i see that Thread Safety is enabled).

However, i always keep getting the message -
 'Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found'
for this code snippet-

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->database_name;
```

Does anyone know the solution to this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable this module? Try `phpinfo();` to see is the module has been loaded

Comment: No. And yeah, i forgot to mention that too - the module is not being shown as loaded in phpinfo() (called from same script). I have added 'extension=php_mongo.dll' to the php.ini file too. Is there anything else to be done ?

Comment: Have you restarted apache ? Did you put the dll into the path that can be read by apache?

Comment: Yeah, i did restart apache. Same error inspite of that. And i have put the dll into C:\xampp\php\ext\ . Is that fine ?

Comment: Enable error logging in php (including start-up errors) and then restart apache and look in the error logs. That might tell you what's going on.

Comment: Error logging is on. The log contains the same record - 'Fatal error Class 'Mongo' not found' !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !! What i did was re-installed Apache and applied the changes. It worked, although i don't know what went wrong in the first place !! Thank you everyone for your help !!

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link - [Error installing MongoDb PHP driver with XAMPP on Max OS Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725577/error-installing-mongodb-php-driver-with-xampp-on-max-os-lion/10726050#10726050) - I think it's possibly the same issue, though it was on Mac OS whereas you're on Windows.

I believe that you may need to install the xampp "Developer Package", required to build additional php extension.

The "Developer Package" can be found here : http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html.

Comment: Thanks ! Although i didnt use it, the information here is quite useful and ill remember it for future reference.

Comment: No worries, good to know. A complete re-install sounds very extreme though!

Comment: Yeah, i know. But i needed it working fast and i was at my wit's end, so i thought of trying it !!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you forgive something .. Mongo don't understand a class unknow so you have to do that :

```
$mongo = new MongoClient();
$db = $mongo->database_name;
```