# view HTML portion of php file in mac chrome?

Tags: php, html, macos, google-chrome

So I'm working on some HTML in a php page, and I want to view the styling/HTML in a web browser. On my windows machine, when I drag the php file to the chrome window, it will render the HTML portions. On my mac, if I do this, it will attempt to save the php file. How do I configure it so that it renders the HTML instead of trying to save it?

Comment: Chrome cannot render PHP.  That is done on the server side.  It is possible that when you are dragging it over on your windows machine it is mapping it to where you are running a local PHP server and on your mac it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like your Mac doesn't have apache turned on?

Or possibly PHP isn't enabled if you do?

[Easiest way to activate PHP and MySQL on Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard), 10.7 (Lion), 10.8 (Mountain Lion)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293484/easiest-way-to-activate-php-and-mysql-on-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard)

Comment: I enabled it but I don't think that's the issue. I'm wondering if it has something to do with configuring chrome

Comment: I tried safari and that just displays the contents of the file as text, instead of rendering the HTML elements, strange..

Comment: Based on that I'm still thinking you don't have PHP enabled properly or have you not restarted apache after you enabled it?